# Blank file created even when missing admin privileges

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am new to chef and started my very first lesson.  When running my recipe without privilege, an exception is thrown (for which I am glad) but a blank 'hello.txt' is also created.  Isn't misleading to have this blank 'hello.txt'?

*hello_recipe.rb*

```
file 'hello.txt' do
   content 'Welcome to Chef'
end

>chef-apply hello_recipe.rb #=> chef-client doesn't have administrator privileges...
```

How do I rollback this change (i.e. empty text file)?

Comment: `chef` won't need administrator privileges for that. I got the following: http://pastebin.com/ykF9swm1

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem.But the reason is that when using the chef-client we need cookbooks to used.For a single filename.rb file we use chef-apply to get the file content.

In your your case,everything is worked fine with creating the hello.txt file but the content is missing.

> so,you just type cmd in run and don't click for enter.while typing cmd
>   the command prompt pops up.Just right click on the cmd and choose run
>   as administrator and open it.

Now work in this cmd, your expected execution will be performed.